# Getting an optional firebase database value when it shouldn't be optional

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am running the following query to get a value from the snapshot, but the value is returning as optional.

```
ref.child("PGroups").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    let groupName = String(rest.childSnapshotForPath("/GroupName").value)
    print(groupName)
})
```

and am getting the following printed statement: `"Optional(Name)"` as appoosed to just: `"Name"`

Comment: Why don't you think the value should be optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add an exclamation point to tell the compiler to unwrap the optional:

`print(groupName!)` should print `"Name"`

Alternatively you could also change your code to something like this:

```
ref.child("PGroups").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
    let groupName = snapshotValue["GroupName"] as! String
    print(groupName)
})
```