# Is it possible to save the same autoID in firebase database and storage?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Im trying to organize my Database and Storage. And i want to use the same autoID it generated for the user in database to be used in my Storage. Is it possible?

this is the code that i use to save the profile photo.

```
 let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email else { return }

 let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(email+"/ProfilePhoto/\("Profile Photo")")
```

Instead of using the email. i want the user autoID in database to be used.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use the user's unique ID in Firebase Authentication?  That usually makes more sense to store per-user data.

Comment: how do i get the ID in Firebase Authentication to be used for the userID in database?

Comment: this is what i use to save the user in database  Database.database().reference().child("User").childByAutoId().setValue(UserDictionary) and how to use the same ID in Firebase Storage

Comment: Please don't use emails as node keys or paths. It will contain characters that cannot be used as a key and then you have to parse it and have a bunch of extra code. Just use the users uid as the key and also as the path the where their data is stored in storage. So it woud look like */storage/uid/ProfilePhoto* where the uid is `currentUser.uid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most appropriate way to store per user information in both Cloud Storage and Realtime Database (and Cloud Storage for that matter) is the signed-in user's unique ID (UID).

```
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Protocols/UserInfo.html#uid

The auto id generated by Realtime Database won't uniquely identify the user. It will return a random value every time.

Comment: it worked. but how come theres a word "Optional" in the user in Firebase database?

Comment: Thats because Doug uses a `?` to find the user. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460412/getting-an-optional-firebase-database-value-when-it-shouldnt-be-optional

Answer (score -1):

To get the UID of the current user:

```
let uid = Auth.auth().current?.uid
print(uid!)
```

Comment: it worked. but how come theres a word "Optional" in the user in Firebase database? See image above

Comment: Because you have saved an optional string in the database. You must make it not optional with **!**.

Comment: For example:

var str: String?
str = "Hello"
print (str) // Optional ("Hello")

var str: String!
str = "Hello"
print (str) // "Hello"

Comment: @Nick It is **not** because *Because you have saved an optional string in the database*. Also, Auth.auth() does not have a `current` var, it's `.currentUser`. It's optional because the `currentUser` var could be `nil` if there is no current user, so it, and it's properties could be nil. You should never force unwrap it with a ! in a production app as it can cause your app to crash. When a var can be nil, Swift uses an Optional property - which has nothing to do with Firebase or storing data.

Comment: Here's a link with a great explanation and best practices. [optionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu/32170457#32170457)